# Can't get regex to strip out named HTML tag

Tags: c#, regex

I have some html :-

```
<blockquote>This is a quote</blockquote>
<p>This is the main post</p>
```

I want to remove the blockquote and its contents
. I've tried : -

```
string strippedPost = Regex.Replace(post, "<blockquote>(.*?)</blockquote>", "");
```

But not had any luck with it. Is there a problem with the regex?

update: also tried

```
string strippedPost = Regex.Replace(post, @"<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>", "");
```

Comment: Maybe escape `/`.

Comment: I tried that but still no joy

Comment: For all but the most trivial exercises an HTML Parser is the tool for the job; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Add `RegexOptions.Singleline` as third parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
 strippedPost = Regex.Replace(post, "<blockquote>(.|\n)*?</blockquote>", "");
```

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)*?`. Use `RegexOptions.Singleline` to enable `.` to match newlines.